# How can I use native sql query in C# by entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I want to use this query

```
select datename (dw, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)AS DAY ;
```

to get week day name and use it to insert record to table.

how can I use this query by entity framework

I use this method but it doesn't work:

```
   private void GetDayName(DateTime ReportDate,out string DayName)
    {
     using (var context = new Daily_ReportEntities3())
     {
       var day_name= context.ExecuteStoreQuery ("select datename (dw,'|| + ReportDate + ||') as NameOfDay", null).ToList();

    DayName = day_name=.ToString();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek` ?

Comment: Nice questions here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute transact SQL statements from Entity Framework directly.

But you can [Execute Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739018%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from within `ObjectContext`.

First define a scalar value function returning data you need and next import it to your Store model. You'll be able to execute it via [ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739018%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

---

PS. Consider implementing your functionality using [System.Globalization.Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, that can supply the information about day names based on certain culture.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this:

```
var day_name = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>
     ("select datename (dw,'|| + ReportDate + ||') as NameOfDay").FirstOrDefault<string>();
```

see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.103%29.aspx